# Difference of two list columns in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with two columns that are list type.
I am trying to get a third column which gives me the difference of these two columns as a list into a column.

eg :

Assume the below dataframe with 2 columns :

```
+--------------+------------+
|          col1|        col2|
+--------------+------------+
|[10, 20,30,40]|    [10, 20]|
+--------------+------------+
```

I am trying to get a third column whose value is a list which contains the elements of col1 that are not present in col2. So my resultant data frame will look as below:

```
+--------------+------------+---------+
|          col1|        col2|    col3 |
+--------------+------------+---------+
|[10, 20,30,40]|    [10, 20]| [30, 40]|
+--------------+------------+---------+
```

here's some code to create a sample dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(["10","20","30"],["10","20","30"])]["age","id"])

df.show()
+------------+------------+
|         age|          id|
+------------+------------+
|[10, 20, 30]|[10, 20, 30]|
+------------+------------+

df.select(df.age - df.id).show()
```

I was trying in different ways as above but could not resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [array_except](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_except)(col1, col2) which returns the elements that are present in col1 but not in col2 **without duplicates**.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(["10","20","30"],["10","20","30"]), (["10","20","30"],["10","20"]), (["10","20","30"],["10","20","50"])],["age","id"])

df=df.withColumn('col3', F.array_except('age', 'id'))

#In case you want to get the difference between both columns
#df=df.withColumn('col3', F.array_union(F.array_except('age', 'id'), F.array_except('id', 'age')))

df.show()
```

You need to use an udf in case you are working with spark < 2.4:

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(["10","20","30"],["10","20","30"]), (["10","20","30"],["10","20"]), (["10","20","30"],["10","20","50"])],["age","id"])

def arrayDiff(col1, col2):
    #set will remove duplicates
    diff = set(col1) - set(col2)
    return list(diff)

diff=F.udf(arrayDiff, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

df=df.withColumn('col3', diff('age', 'id'))

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+------------+----+ 
|         age|          id|col3| 
+------------+------------+----+ 
|[10, 20, 30]|[10, 20, 30]|  []| 
|[10, 20, 30]|    [10, 20]|[30]| 
|[10, 20, 30]|[10, 20, 50]|[30]| 
+------------+------------+----+
```

Comment: be careful about the side-effect of `array_except()`, it will remove duplicates from the final list which might delete some extra records.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. array_except will return the elements which are in col1 but not in col2, without duplicates. Which records might be deleted?

Comment: check age = *["10","20","30","30"]*, id=["10","20"], `array_except` will yield `["30"]` instead of ["30", "30"]. have to know if the OP wants this side-effect or there is no dupes in the original arrays.

Comment: Looks like array_except function works from 2.4.0 spark version. How could you resolve the above issue in 2.3 version?

Comment: I have edited my answer to address this. Please have a look.